# What does the below comparison means?

Tags: regex, oracle

Could any one explain why NOVALIDATE is written their and why alpha betwnn two ":" and "[]"

```
ALTER TABLE CUSTOMERS
ADD CONSTRAINT cust_f_name
CHECK(REGEXP_LIKE(cust_first_name,'[[:alpha:]]'))NOVALIDATE ;
```

and what does

```
REGEXP_LIKE(cust_first_name,'^[0-9]')
```

and

```
REGEXP_LIKE(cust_first_name,'^A-Z')
```

means ? is that numbers not allowed?

Comment: [Read all about `alpha` here.](http://psoug.org/reference/regexp.html) Is this really about Microsoft SQL Server 2008?

Comment: I came across when solving a qustion from IZO045 PLSQL certification exam ?

Comment: One question at a time, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are regular expressions, used in Oracle as a table constraint.

- `[:alpha:]` matches any character from the alpha POSIX class; that is, alphabetic characters (a-z and A-Z).
- The `^`, in the context of `^[0-9]`, means look from the beginning of the string. `[0-9]` is the class of numbers (i.e., 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9)
- `^A-Z` means negate the class `A-Z`; so it would match anything that didn't contain an upper case alphabetic character.

`NOVALIDATE` means that, once the constraint is added to the table `CUSTOMERS`, Oracle will not check that any current entries violate the constraint and only apply it to newly inserted records.

Comment: *Comment from user3752500:* I don't think ``^A-Z`` means negate ``A-Z``, but the beginning with ``A-Z`` instead of that.